# High response times in HDD. MFT, fragmentation or even halted disk?

Tags: hard-drive, defragment, mft

I am experiencing **really high response times** im my HDD, which can go around 13000ms (from Win8 Task Manager). This occurs when starting up windows and for at least 3-4 minutes, also when doing extensive copy (lots of files). The average read/write speed during that time is around 50Mb/s (total). This behavior started after the first or second partition resize (see below), before that the disk was going really fast.

My Win8 partition is 50% full and recently defragged. The partition had been resized 4 times, from 40Gb to 100, to 350 and to 600Gb (I deleted other partitions). Now, the whole drive only has this one partition.

The HDD drivers are the ones windows downloaded and the SMART status is healthy. Disk is Sata3 in RAID disk controller mode (single drive) and is the [WD wd6400aars](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136737).

After my little research below (which showed more problems) I can't tell if the disk is halted in any way, if the MFT is fragmented or positioned at the wrong place or if there is something else going on here.

## My little research

### Benchmarking

Turns out really good using ATTO Disk Benchmark, but...

[image]

but in Crystal DiskMark during the last 4 benchmarks I have 0.5 to 1 Mb/s and average response times **around 15000ms** (cannot be seen here)

[image]

### Windows Resource Monitor

During startup the windows resource monitor utility showed that MFT had the highest response times (around 8000ms) between all files being used during that time, no matter which process was accessing it. Note that no heavy application runs during startup, besides basic stuff like skype, dropbox etc.

### Fragmentation

After the last partition resize, I defragged using Defraggler and the windows utility 2 times. This took some 5 hours each time and since the problem still remains I installed Perfect Disk which revealed two strange issues:

- Defraggler finds the MFT in the middle of the partition and Perfect disk at the beginning of the drive.
- The **most fragmented** files are the last two files copied to the disk. The Perfect Disk itself. How can this be true, it was just copied into a disk with lots of free space!

### Defraggler

[image]

### Perfect Disk

(bigger image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP94V.png))
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**There may be a partition alignment problem with your hard drive.**  Your WD6400AARS is an [Advanced Media Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) drive that uses 4K sector sizes.  If your OS partition is not properly aligned on this 4K boundary it will lead to much slower than expected disk drive performance due to a process of [translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format#512e) the drive must perform.

Western Digital offers for free [WD Align Windows](http://support.wdc.com/product/downloadsw.asp?sid=128) utility on the [WD6400AARS Support Page](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?modelno=WD6400AARS%20&x=13&y=6) to correct this issue.  The utility will analyze your disk and report whether you have a misaligned partition and offer to correct it if so.  While this is supposed to be a non-destructive operation, you should **back up your data before running this utility**.

[This](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5341/session/L3RpbWUvMTMwMDIyODQwMS9zaWQvaVZtZEcqb2s%3D) Western Digital support page describes the Alignment Tool's functionality in even more depth.

Comment: Cool info I wasn't aware of. Unfortunately the utility shows the partition as aligned.

Comment: +1, but I doubted this was the issue as the OP's computer runs Windows 8, which has full support for 512e Advanced Format drives and should never cause an [Alignment 1](http://www.idema.org/?page_id=2153) condition even after multiple partition resizes.

Comment: @DragonLord Agreed. I didn't want to assume the partition was originally created on Win8 even though that likelihood enjoys the greatest odds.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try defragmenting system files like the page file and MFT at boot time. Defraggler offers this option; it will run when you reboot your computer, on a text-mode screen before the Windows lock screen comes up. You can access this functionality under **Boot Time Defrag** in the **Settings** menu. I've done this before and it successfully defragmented the MFT.

Running Windows command-line `defrag` with the undocumented `/b` option, which optimizes for boot speed, may also help.

Comment: pagefile isn't being used, I have lots of RAM. I will try defragging both of them during startup and I'll post the results. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @Odys Your pagefile will be used regardless of how much RAM you have. Windows will copy data in memory to the pagefile so that *if* it needs extra RAM it can free up the memory immediately having already written the data to the pagefile.